# how to get only year from date using Distinct from mysql in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Check the code below:

```
$this->set('hi', $this->posts->find('all',
array('fields'=>array('DISTINCT year(posts.Post_date)'))));
```

I am not getting the correct results ... can anyone help me in this please...

my query is (Select distinct year(post_date) from posts);

Thanks

Comment: use format(fieldname,'Y') as your date

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_format

Comment: Also check your capitalisation, you might need to replace "posts.Post_date" with "Posts.post_date".

Answer (score 3):

replace below

```
`DISTINCT year(posts.Post_date)`
```

with below:-

```
YEAR(DISTINCT posts.Post_date) as year
```

Comment: I'm having a 'Date' column but my cakephp is returning an Cake\I18n\FrozenDate Object. How can I only get Date from it?